# Rails 4 - Bootstrap Popovers - js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to figure out how to get popovers working in my Rails 4 app.

I have bootstrap-sass gem in my app. In accordance with the documentation, I have included the following in my application.js file:

```
/= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
```

I have also tried swapping the require bootstrap for require bootstrap-sprockets (but it makes no difference).

I have another file in my javascripts folder called organisations.js.coffee, with:

```
$('label-with-popover').popover(placement: 'right')
```

In my view, I'm trying to get a popover working, I have:

```
<button type="button"  class="label-with-popover" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="netwerewerwrwe" data-title="test"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>
```

When I try this, the button does nothing when I click on it.

Can anyone see what needs to happen to get this working? I'm not sure if I'm supposed to put script tags around the line i have in the coffee file. I tried it, but it makes no difference to this problem.

Comment: You should only have class defined once - i.e. `class="label-with-popover btn btn-default"`. Some browsers will only take the last class statement which might be why jquery can't find it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the proper selector in your jQuery so the popover is not being applied to the right class. You need:

```
$('.label-with-popover').popover(placement: 'right');
```

Before you were just selecting an element called `label-with-popover` which doesn't exist. You need to be selecting the class `.label-with-popover`

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt work. Nothing happens when I click on the button. I can see in my console inspector this error message: 10TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$(document)', '$' is undefined)

Comment: Then you don't have jQuery. Not sure if the above is a typo or not but you need it to be 2 slashes: `//= require jquery`

Comment: It's a typo. I have two slashes. How do i make jQuery work? i have other jQuery assets working.

Comment: Do you have `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your gemfile?

Comment: But you said `$(document)` says `$` is undefined. Where are your working jQuery assets?

Comment: Also, this may be ridiculously obvious but have you restarted your server since adding all of this stuff?